# How to find the maximum sum of nodes in a tree

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree, dynamic-programming

I am given two arrays, one defines the relationship of nodes and other gives the values of nodes.

```
arr1={0,1,1,1,3,3,4}
arr2={22,100,3,3,4,5,9}
```

arr1 defines the relationship, i.e. root node is 1st element and parent of node 2,3 and 4th is node 1 and parent of node 5th and 6th is root 3rd and parent of node 7th is node 4.

arr2 gives the value of nodes, node 1 have a  value of 22 and node 2 has got a value of 100.

I have to find the maximum sum of nodes such that no two included nodes have a parent or a grand parent relationship.

sample input:

```
a[i]=[0,1,1,1,3,3,6,6]
b[i]=[1,2,3,4,5,100,7,8]

output: 111
```

I am new to DS and ALGO and not able to even think of the solution. Help is needed thanks.
Any type of help will do.

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of traversing a tree?

Comment: Can you simply print all the values in your tree?

Comment: Great grand parent relationship (or more distant) would be OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it using `Dynamic Programming`.
Consider an array `dp[]` which stores the answer for each of the vertex and its subtree.

Now state of `DP` would be,

```
dp[currentVertex] = max(sum of all children's dp[] ,
                        b[currentVertex] + sum of all vertices' dp[] whose 
                        greatGrandParent is currentVertex])
```

You need to build `DP` table using bottom-up approach. So start from the leaves.

Answer would be `dp[root]` after all the calculation.